# Calling Snowflake stored procedure errors with invalid param type even though it appears to be defined correctly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to define a Snowflake stored procedure that accepts a single `VARCHAR` parameter. However, when calling the procedure, I get the following error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 0 at position -1 Invalid argument types for function 'SP_TRUNCATE_IVR_STAGE': (VARCHAR(4))

Here is the procedure definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_NAME(ENVIRONMENT VARCHAR)
```

Here is the calling statement:

```
call SP_NAME('_DEV');
```

Note: I have created many stored procedures with more complex signatures, I suspect this is some kind of bug. I created a new procedure with the same param signature and a different name from scratch and it worked. Is there some kind clash from stored procedure signatures? For example, if we previously have defined a procedure with the same name accepting a double as the first param, will it cause issue? I wouldn't think so because you can purposely define procedures with different signatures.

Comment: Snowflake stored procedures do support signature overloading. It should be picking up the one with the single varchar input as the signature. What happens when you run `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES where PROCEDURE_NAME = 'SP_TRUNCATE_IVR_STAGE';`?

Comment: Can you share the output of "select get_ddl('procedure', 'SP_TRUNCATE_IVR_STAGE(varchar)');"

Comment: select get_ddl('procedure', 'SP_TRUNCATE_IVR_STAGE(varchar)'); returns the DDL used to define the SP.  Here is the first part of the output:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_TRUNCATE_IVR_EVENT"("ENVIRONMENT" VARCHAR(16777216))